# php time function

Tags: php, sql, mysql

what is wrong with this sql query? he is crying on `NOW()` :(

```
("INSERT INTO " . PREFIX . "messages (from, to, title, message, date) 
VALUES (" . $from . ", " . $to . ", " . $subject . ", " . $message . ", NOW())");
```

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: Also, consider wrapping your variables into `'`.

Comment: And what is the output from: `DESCRIBE MESSAGES` in phpmyadmin

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: I hope you have escaped those variables using `mysql_real_escape_string` or something like that before passing it to the query.

Comment: Please provide the error message. Error messages are there for a reason. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Are you using MySQL or Microsoft SQL Server? NOW() doesn't work in SQL Server; need to use GETDATE() instead.

Comment: `GETDATE()` is SQL Server specific - this question is for **MySQL**.  `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` is ANSI standard however, supported on both.

Comment: @Scott: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now ?

Comment: Woops, I've been trapped in the SQL Server world for too long.

Comment: FYI: the original question did not specify SQL or MySQL

Answer (score -2):

Maybe using current time stamp would be better idea, I don't know it, just type timestamp in mysql you'll find it on google